# Having if condition in laravel

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my condition in php, i am trying it to convert to laravel

```
     <?php 
      if ($DriverDetail['IsActive']=='1') 
      {
        ?>
        <span class='account-active'></span>
        <?php
      }
      else
      {
       ?>
         <span class='account-blocked'></span>
       <?php
      }
      ?>
```

I tried with

```
{{ $DriverDetail['IsActive'] }}
```

and concatinated the `<span class='account-blocked'></span>` inside the `{{}}`

But which is the best way to have the condition in laravel which is equivalent to my php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<span class='{{ $DriverDetail['IsActive'] ? 'account-active' : 'account-blocked' }}'></span>
```

Or, if you want the whole span separated:

```
{{ $DriverDetail['IsActive'] ? "<span class='account-active'></span>" : "<span class='account-blocked'></span>" }}
```

This is using a ternary operator (docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)).  Basically, any value that evaluates to a boolean true will output the first expression (after the '?'), otherwise it outputs the second expression (after the ':'). In this case, the string '1', or even the number 1, evaluates to a boolean true, so the ternary operator will evaluate to the "true" expression ('account-active').  Implicit boolean conversions are covered in the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: Great, can you please explain how it checks for the value `1` ?

Comment: @Chennai I have updated the answer to provide the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this...**

```
 @if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

With the blade templating system, a clear way would be:

```
@if ($DriverDetail['IsActive'])
  <span class='account-active'></span>
@else
  <span class='account-blocked'></span>
@endif
```